# Google BigQuery SQL find all records with ID in array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Google Big Query on-demand prices for queries are $5 per TB of data searched when the query is executed.  I have a 2TB database and want to reduce costs.

My goal is to return specific fields from records whose ID is in a list. Doing this record by record significantly grows costs quickly.  However if I use an SQL query that uses an array of IDs and simply returns all records where the ID is in the list, then I can compact hundreds of queries into one query and simply sort through the results.

Here is an example of the query I used for a single record.

```
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM `database.table`
WHERE field1 = 'US14236932' LIMIT 1
```

I would like a query similar to this:

```
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM `database.table`
WHERE field1 
IN ('US14236932', 'US14236933', 'US14236934', 'US14236935')
```

I have read the [BigQuery documentation on arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays), but did not see an example similar to my needs.

Comment: Drop the `select *` and choose only the columns you need.  That is the simplest way to reduce costs.

Comment: I don't want the simplest way to reduce costs.  I want the method used in the OP.  I'm aware of what you are saying, but you can assume that if I'm using * I need all the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that way:

```
SELECT * FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications`
WHERE application_number_formatted 
IN UNNEST(['US14236932', 'US14236933', 'US14236934', 'US14236935'])
```

Comment: Looks like this effective.